# Vertical alignment within span is not working with special characters

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the text vertically, but the star is not aligning, How do I align them vertically center?

```css
.operators {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.operators > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.operators > li span{
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
}
```

```html
<ul class="operators">
  <li>
    <span>+</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>-</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>*</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>=</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The characters are display exactly how they should. You could manipulate each one with positioning, but that seems senseless. If this is for something like a calculator keypad, maybe use SVG instead?

Comment: The problem is that the characters being used aren't designed for what they (appear) to be being used for - at least in the case of the star shape which is an asterisk (and therefore raised up) rather than a multiplication sign - though we use it for that in programming languages - and the - isn't aligned either as it's actually a hyphen not a minus sign, though again it's what is used in programming languages for minus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try another asterisk that is centered. Unicode Asterisk Operator with HTML entity `&#8727;`
However note that some browsers might not show this correctly

```css
.operators {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.operators > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.operators > li span{
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
}
```

```html
<ul class="operators">
  <li>
    <span>+</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>-</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>&#8727;</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>=</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wish I could change the values but have a limitation, Will try to handle it with position.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the hyphen nor the asterisk are correctly aligned. This is because they are defined as to be used for different purposes, not for minus and multiply though that is how many programming languages use them as they are present on most keyboards.

The correct (i.e. consistent with the Unicode definitions) signs for minus and multiplication in HTML are

Minus: HTML `&#8722;` which gives you − see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#:%7E:text=In%20APL%20a%20raised%20minus%20sign%20%28Unicode%20U%2B00AF%29,denoted%20by%20an%20underscore%2C%20as%20in%20_5%20.)

Multiply: HTML `&#215;` which gives you × see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign)

For a calculator type application then these signs are probably the ones to use.

However, if you are trying to use them in some way to discuss programming then you probably need to stick to using the hyphen and asterisk. The fact that they aren't aligned with the other symbols would at least then be consistent with what the user sees when writing code in an editor.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. Seems I have limitation with these characters as they are being generated dynamically.